# Make Maven to copy dependencies into target/lib

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, maven-2, maven-3

How do I get my project's runtime dependencies copied into the `target/lib` folder?

As it is right now, after `mvn clean install` the `target` folder contains only my project's jar, but none of the runtime dependencies.

Comment: Why do you need this ? What is the type of your maven project ? jar ?

Comment: The type of my maven project is JAR.  I need this because there are a lot of dependencies and I'm trying deploy the jar as an executable.

Comment: Caution with assemblies - if you have overlapping packages/classes between the deps, you will probably have a bad time.

Answer (score 298):

This works for me:

```xml
<project>
  ...
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>qa</id>
      <build>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <phase>install</phase>
                <goals>
                  <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                  <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib</outputDirectory>
                </configuration>
              </execution>
            </executions>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </build>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
</project>
```

Comment: If you want this to happen all the time, remove the <profiles>...<profile> wrappers and make the <build> tag be just under <project>

Comment: @Georgy this does not coy the jars in lib/ , but includes the classes in the compiled project

Comment: This is fine, but it is copying test dependencies too. I add to myself the `excludeScope` option (http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/copy-dependencies-mojo.html).

Comment: Work well but it is not required to place the build tag inside the profile tags.

Comment: Note: `<excludeScope>test</excludeScope>` goes inside the `configuration` node.

Comment: Maybe it would be more appropriate if the phase were `package` instead of `install`

Answer (score 121):

```
mvn install dependency:copy-dependencies
```

Works for me with dependencies directory created in target folder. Like it!

Comment: Thank you for this simple option. I used the package target instead but otherwise did what I was looking for.

Comment: dont know how this is not hte accepted answer? anyway , if you want to send dependencies to specific dir, for example called 'lib' , can use `mvn dependency:copy-dependencies -DoutputDirectory=lib/`

Answer (score 96):

The best approach depends on what you want to do:

- If you want to bundle your dependencies into a WAR or EAR file, then simply set the packaging type of your project to EAR or WAR. Maven will bundle the dependencies into the right location.
- If you want to create a JAR file that includes your code along with all your dependencies, then use the [assembly](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/) plugin with the *jar-with-dependencies* descriptor. Maven will generate a complete JAR file with all your classes plus the classes from any dependencies.
- If you want to simply pull your dependencies into the target directory interactively, then use the [dependency](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/) plugin to copy your files in.
- If you want to pull in the dependencies for some other type of processing, then you will probably need to generate your own plugin. There are APIs to get the list of dependencies, and their location on disk. You will have to take it from there...

Answer (score 47):

All you need is the following snippet inside pom.xml's `build/plugins`:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>prepare-package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib</outputDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

The above will run in the `package` phase when you run

```
mvn clean package
```

And the dependencies will be copied to the outputDirectory specified in the snippet, i.e. `lib` in this case.

If you only want to do that occasionally, then no changes to pom.xml are required.  Simply run the following:

```
mvn clean package dependency:copy-dependencies
```

To override the default location, which is `${project.build.directory}/dependencies`, add a System property named `outputDirectory`, i.e.

```
    -DoutputDirectory=${project.build.directory}/lib
```

Answer (score 39):

Take a look at the [Maven dependency plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/index.html), specifically, the [dependency:copy-dependencies goal](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/copy-dependencies-mojo.html).  Take a look at [the example](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/usage.html) under the heading **The dependency:copy-dependencies mojo**.  Set the **outputDirectory** configuration property to ${basedir}/target/lib (I believe, you'll have to test).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Alternatively, you could use ${project.build.directory}/lib rather than ${basedir}/target/lib

Answer (score 36):

If you want to do this on an occasional basis (and thus don't want to change your POM), try this command-line:

```
mvn dependency:copy-dependencies -DoutputDirectory=${project.build.directory}/lib
```

If you omit the [last argument](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/copy-dependencies-mojo.html#outputDirectory), the dependences are placed in `target/dependencies`.

Comment: thanks! this is the easiest way to just copy the libs that would be required by a project into a folder somewhere so you can copy them somewhere else if need be, e.g. a non maven based project. Note that of course you can just pass in a hardcoded folder to use if you like, e.g. `mvn dependency:copy-dependencies -DoutputDirectory=./lib
`

Comment: Can you do it out of pom.xml?

Answer (score 34):

A simple and elegant solution for the case where one needs to copy the dependencies to a target directory without using any other phases of maven (I found this very useful when working with Vaadin).

Complete pom example:

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>groupId</groupId>
    <artifactId>artifactId</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mybatis</groupId>
            <artifactId>mybatis-spring</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <phase>process-sources</phase>

                            <goals>
                                <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                            </goals>

                            <configuration>
                                <outputDirectory>${targetdirectory}</outputDirectory>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Then run `mvn process-sources`

The jar file dependencies can be found in `/target/dependency`

Comment: maven-dependency-plugin (goals "copy-dependencies", "unpack") is not supported by m2e. :-(

Comment: @Gobliins use ${project.build.directory}/lib instead of ${targetdirectory}

Answer (score 25):

Try something like this:

```xml
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.4</version>
<configuration>
    <archive>
        <manifest>  
            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
            <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
            <mainClass>MainClass</mainClass>
        </manifest>
    </archive>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>copy</id>
            <phase>install</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>
                    ${project.build.directory}/lib
                </outputDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: @Thomas I think it's `maven clean install`, then you will find `lib` in `target`

Comment: what would I have to do to copy only 1 dependency?

Comment: <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix> helped me a lot. Thank you!

Comment: Would replace the `install` phase with `process-resources` so that the dependencies are copied before the `build` goal runs

Answer (score 11):

supposing

- you don't want to alter the pom.xml
- you don't want test scoped (e.g. junit.jar) or provided dependencies (e.g. wlfullclient.jar)

here ist what worked for me:

```
mvn install dependency:copy-dependencies -DincludeScope=runtime -DoutputDirectory=target/lib
```

Answer (score 5):

If you want to deliver a bundle of your application jar, together with all its dependencies and some scripts to invoke the MainClass, look at the [appassembler-maven-plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/appassembler/appassembler-maven-plugin/).

The following configuration will generate scripts for Window and Linux to launch the application (with a generated path referencing all the dependency jars, download all dependencies (into a lib folder below target/appassembler). The [assembly plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/) can then be used to package the whole appassembler directory to a zip which is installed/deployed along with the jar to the repository.

```xml
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>appassembler-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>generate-jsw-scripts</id>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>generate-daemons</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <!--declare the JSW config -->
          <daemons>
            <daemon>
              <id>myApp</id>
              <mainClass>name.seller.rich.MyMainClass</mainClass>
              <commandLineArguments>
                <commandLineArgument>start</commandLineArgument>
              </commandLineArguments>
              <platforms>
                <platform>jsw</platform>
              </platforms>              
            </daemon>
          </daemons>
          <target>${project.build.directory}/appassembler</target>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
      <execution>
        <id>assemble-standalone</id>
        <phase>integration-test</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>assemble</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <programs>
            <program>
              <mainClass>name.seller.rich.MyMainClass</mainClass>
              <!-- the name of the bat/sh files to be generated -->
              <name>mymain</name>
            </program>
          </programs>
          <platforms>
            <platform>windows</platform>
            <platform>unix</platform>
          </platforms>
          <repositoryLayout>flat</repositoryLayout>
          <repositoryName>lib</repositoryName>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2-beta-4</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <phase>integration-test</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>single</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <descriptors>
            <descriptor>src/main/assembly/archive.xml</descriptor>
          </descriptors>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

The assembly descriptor (in src/main/assembly) to package the direcotry as a zip would be:

```xml
<assembly>
  <id>archive</id>
  <formats>
    <format>zip</format>
  </formats>
  <fileSets>
    <fileSet>
     <directory>${project.build.directory}/appassembler</directory>
     <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
    </fileSet>
  </fileSets>
</assembly>
```

Answer (score 4):

If you make your project a war or ear type maven will copy the dependencies.

Answer (score 3):

It's a heavy solution for embedding heavy dependencies, but Maven's [Assembly Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/index.html) does the trick for me.

@[Rich Seller's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1449651/155090) should work, although for simpler cases you should only need this excerpt from the [usage guide](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/usage.html):

```
<project>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Your code example doesn't solve the problem, it just bundles everything into a single JAR. Yes, the assembly plugin can be used to achieve this goal, but not like this.

Comment: Although, on further reading, maybe you are responding to [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/97640/force-maven2-to-copy-dependencies-into-target-lib/25441276#comment15792_97640).

Comment: it's been so long that i don't really remember … plus i've gotten rather rusty since focusing on Linux administration at my last firm — but thank you for the feedback!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the the [Shade Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/) to create an uber jar in which you can bundle all your 3rd party dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

Just to spell out what has already been said in brief. I wanted to create an executable JAR file that included my dependencies along with my code. This worked for me:

(1) In the pom, under <build><plugins>, I included:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2-beta-5</version>
    <configuration>
        <archive>
            <manifest>
                <mainClass>dk.certifikat.oces2.some.package.MyMainClass</mainClass>
            </manifest>
        </archive>
        <descriptorRefs>
            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
        </descriptorRefs>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

(2) Running mvn compile assembly:assembly produced the desired my-project-0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar in the project's target directory.

(3) I ran the JAR with java -jar my-project-0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar

Comment: main class not found in (3)

Answer (score 0):

If you're having problems related to dependencies not appearing in the WEB-INF/lib file when running on a Tomcat server in Eclipse, take a look at this:

[ClassNotFoundException DispatcherServlet when launching Tomcat (Maven dependencies not copied to wtpwebapps)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4777026/classnotfoundexception-dispatcherservlet-when-launching-tomcat-maven-dependencie)

You simply had to add the Maven Dependencies in Project Properties > Deployment Assembly.

Answer (score 0):

You could place a `settings.xml` file in your project directory with a basic config like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
    <localRepository>.m2/repository</localRepository>
    <interactiveMode/>
    <offline/>
    <pluginGroups/>
    <servers/>
    <mirrors/>
    <proxies/>
    <profiles/>
    <activeProfiles/>
</settings>
```

More information on these settings can be found in the official [Maven docs](https://maven.apache.org/settings.html#simple-values).
Note that the path is resolved relative to the directory where the actual settings file resides in unless you enter an absolute path.

When you execute maven commands you can use the settings file as follows:

```sh
mvn -s settings.xml clean install
```

Side note: I use this in my GitLab CI/CD pipeline in order to being able to cache the maven repository for several jobs so that the dependencies don't need to be downloaded for every job execution. GitLab can only cache files or directories from your project directory and therefore I reference a directory wihtin my project directory.