# How to copy folder from within a zip using NSIS?

Tags: zip, nsis, installation

I'm using NSIS to write an installer.  I'd like to copy the 'lib' directory contained in a zip.  Is it possible to specify that the contents of sampleZip.zip/lib is copied to, say $INSTDIR\lib?

The basic idea of what I want is this, though it obviously doesn't work:

```
File /r sampleZip.zip\lib\*
```

Any ideas on how this can be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than install the plugin, I just copied the libraries I needed using the plugin described at this answer [force Maven2 to copy dependencies into target/lib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/97640/force-maven2-to-copy-dependencies-into-target-lib).

Since I was the one building the zip file I wanted to access, I felt this way would be more reliable.

Thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

NSIS does not have native support for this, you need to use one of the unzip plugins: [NsUnzip](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/NsUnzip_plugin), [Nsisunz](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Nsisunz_plug-in) or [ZipDLL](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/ZipDLL_plug-in)