# Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, tomcat, servlets

I am running some servlet code in tomcat in eclipse. It's been working fine but today I get the error `Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace`. The full error looks like this:

```
SEVERE: Allocate exception for servlet RunServlet
org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration     problem: Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace     [http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx]
Offending resource: class path resource [spring/dao.xml]
```

I've had a look at other questions regarding this error, but I don't really understand the answers.

When I look at the target libs, I can see that `spring-tx-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar` is in `WEB-INF/lib`.

Can anyone help me out?

Thanks so much!

EDIT: `dao.xml` starts:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.0.xsd">
```

EDIT: Not sure if this is relevant, but I'm working on a mac book pro, and the latest mac update updated to Java 1.6, and I just switched over my Java preferences to 1.6.

EDIT: I'm also getting the following message in the Tomcat log, but I think I was getting it before and I don't think it's related, but just in case:

```
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.14
Jul 6, 2011 11:59:55 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(/Users/bw/Documents/workspace2/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/core/WEB-INF/lib/servlet-api-2.5.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
```

EDIT: Sorry - didn't see your comments. Here's a listing of the `WEB-INF`.

```
b-ws-macbook-pro:lib bw$ ls -ltr
total 13456
-rw-r--r--  1 bw  staff   62983 May 14 09:26 activation-1.1.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 bw  staff   53082 May 14 09:26 spring-asm-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 bw  staff   60686 May 14 09:26 commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 bw  staff   61379 May 14 09:26 spring-oxm-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 bw  staff    4467 May 14 09:26 aopalliance-1.0.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 bw  staff  100870 May 14 09:26 spring-context-support-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 bw  staff   62086 May 14 09:26 commons-pool-1.3.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 bw  staff  169752 May 14 09:26 spring-expression-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 bw  staff  175412 May 14 09:27 spring-webmvc-portlet-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 bw  staff  121757 May 14 09:27 commons-dbcp-1.2.2.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 bw  staff  321190 May 14 09:27 spring-aop-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 bw  staff  231922 May 14 09:27 spring-tx-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 bw  staff  334327 May 14 09:27 spring-orm-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 bw  staff  371792 May 14 09:27 mybatis-2.3.5.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 bw  staff  382442 May 14 09:27 spring-core-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 bw  staff  418977 May 14 09:27 spring-webmvc-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 bw  staff  388864 May 14 09:27 mail-1.4.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 bw  staff  395587 May 14 09:27 spring-web-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 bw  staff  668861 May 14 09:27 spring-context-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 bw  staff  555410 May 14 09:27 spring-beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 bw  staff  385712 May 14 09:27 spring-jdbc-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 bw  staff  512707 May 14 09:27 mysql-connector-java-5.0.5.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 bw  staff  610790 May 14 09:27 c3p0-0.9.1.2.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 bw  staff  391834 May 14 09:27 log4j-1.2.15.jar
```

EDIT:
Thanks, Christian. It's weird, though, because I DON'T have that file in my jars anyway, and I do list it as provided:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

I'm sure I'm missing something here..

EDIT:
Hmm.. now Tomcat can't even find `applicationContext`. Something weird going on with my setup, I think.

Comment: The message about servlet-api-2.5.jar occurs because that jar file must be provided by the servlet container, i.e. Tomcat, and not by the application. Your WEB-INF/lib should not contain that file. You may need it for compiling your app, though. In Maven, you can use the scope `provided` for the servlet-api dependency. But you may as well keep the file, because Tomcat simply skips and ignores the file.

Comment: Could you add a directory listing of WEB-INF/lib please?

Comment: Gah. I fixed it, but I really don't know how. I read this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4777026/classnotfoundexception-dispatcherservlet-when-launching-tomcat-maven-dependencie

and saw that I had the same thing - a problem listed with the build in the 'markers' pane. I ran the quick fix it suggested and now everything is working again.

Like I said, I hadn't touched it since a couple of days ago. Apparently it just gets confused sometimes. 6 hours later..

Thanks for your suggestions, guys..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gah. I fixed it, but I really don't know how. I read this post [ClassNotFoundException DispatcherServlet when launching Tomcat (Maven dependencies not copied to wtpwebapps)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4777026/classnotfoundexception-dispatcherservlet-when-launching-tomcat-maven-dependenci) and saw that I had the same thing - a problem listed with the build in the 'markers' pane. I ran the quick fix it suggested and now everything is working again. Like I said, I hadn't touched it since a couple of days ago. Apparently it just gets confused sometimes. 6 hours later.. Thanks for your suggestions, guys.

Answer (score 4):

For future references:

Maybe you forgot some spring-XXX dependency.

Por example, in maven check if you have the related dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-XXX</artifactId>
    <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Regards

Answer (score 1):

Change the namespace in dao.xml from

```
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.0.xsd
```

to

```
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
```

(and probably spring-beans too)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately it appears to make no difference. I made the changes, built the app clean, restarter the server. Same problem.

Comment: Hmm, do you have any other versions of the spring-tx jar on the classpath?

Comment: I'm not sure. How would I see the classpath of the tomcat server that I'm running in eclipse? I thought it would just use the jars inside WEB-INF/lib, and there is only one spring-tx jar there?

Comment: Are the spring jars in the top level WEB-INF/lib folder? And not in anything like WEB-INF/lib/spring ?

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem from Eclipse Indigo on Kubuntu. I removed m2e and reinstalled a different version of the connector, http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/updates/m2eclipse-wtp/, and everything runs fine now.