# Error: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org/springframework/asm/ClassVisitor.<init>(I)V

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-aop, cglib

I have these two dependencies in my POM which are i think creating this issue but i have tried many different ways and updated versions but nothing worked for me. Can someone please help.
POM.XML

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

     <dependency>
        <groupId>cglib</groupId>
        <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

[image]

Comment: Do you have the full stacktrace and your source code (an extract can be enough)?

Comment: Looks like you have the same problem
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2432471/error-java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-org-objectweb-asm-classwriter-initiv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution to your Question**

1. It seems there is a JAR conflict while managing your dependencies.
2. In Spring 4.2.0, the ClassVisitor class have been included in Spring-core-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar, Please find the below image. Hence there is no need to include spring-asm-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar which I have found in your dependencies.
   [image: ClassVisitor]
3. It is always recommended to use [Bill of Materials](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/spring-framework-bom/4.2.0.RELEASE/spring-framework-bom-4.2.0.RELEASE.pom) when you are using Spring 3.2.X and above versions.
4. Please remove the **CGLIB Proxy** from dependency, as it is no longer needed when you are using [Spring 3.2.X version](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/) and above. Please refer the spring-framework documentation for this.
5. Finally your POM should be like this below. Humbly requesting you to ignore the hibernate and slf4j dependencies.

   ```
                                               <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
                                             <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
                                             <groupId>org.springframework.samples</groupId>
                                             <artifactId>simpleSpring</artifactId>
                                             <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

                                             <properties>

                                                   <!-- Generic properties -->
                                                   <java.version>1.8</java.version>
                                                   <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
                                                   <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>

                                                   <!-- Spring -->
                                                   <spring-framework.version>4.2.0.RELEASE</spring-framework.version>

                                                   <!-- Hibernate / JPA -->
                                                   <hibernate.version>4.2.1.Final</hibernate.version>

                                                   <!-- Logging -->
                                                   <logback.version>1.0.13</logback.version>
                                                   <slf4j.version>1.7.5</slf4j.version>

                                                   <!-- Test -->
                                                   <junit.version>4.11</junit.version>

                                               </properties>
                                               <dependencies>
                                                 <dependency>
                                                   <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                                                   <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
                                                   <version>4.2.0.RELEASE</version>
                                                 </dependency>
                                                 <dependency>
                                                   <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                                                   <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
                                                   <version>4.2.0.RELEASE</version>
                                                 </dependency>
                                                 <dependency>
                                                   <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                                                   <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
                                                   <version>4.2.0.RELEASE</version>
                                                 </dependency>
                                                 <dependency>
                                                   <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                                                   <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
                                                   <version>4.2.0.RELEASE</version>
                                                 </dependency>
                                                 <dependency>
                                                   <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                                                   <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
                                                   <version>4.2.0.RELEASE</version>
                                                 </dependency>
                                                 <dependency>
                                                   <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                                                   <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                                                   <version>4.2.0.RELEASE</version>
                                                 </dependency>
                                                 <dependency>
                                                   <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                                                   <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
                                                   <version>4.2.0.RELEASE</version>
                                                 </dependency>
                                                 <dependency>
                                                   <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                                                   <artifactId>spring-instrument</artifactId>
                                                   <version>4.2.0.RELEASE</version>
                                                 </dependency>
                                                 <dependency>
                                                   <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                                                   <artifactId>spring-instrument-tomcat</artifactId>
                                                   <version>4.2.0.RELEASE</version>
                                                 </dependency>
                                                 <dependency>
                                                   <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                                                   <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
                                                   <version>4.2.0.RELEASE</version>
                                                 </dependency>
                                                 <dependency>
                                                   <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                                                   <artifactId>spring-jms</artifactId>
                                                   <version>4.2.0.RELEASE</version>
                                                 </dependency>
                                                 <dependency>
                                                   <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                                                   <artifactId>spring-messaging</artifactId>
                                                   <version>4.2.0.RELEASE</version>
                                                 </dependency>
                                                 <dependency>
                                                   <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                                                   <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
                                                   <version>4.2.0.RELEASE</version>
                                                 </dependency>
                                                 <dependency>
                                                   <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                                                   <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
                                                   <version>4.2.0.RELEASE</version>
                                                 </dependency>
                                                 <dependency>
                                                   <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                                                   <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
                                                   <version>4.2.0.RELEASE</version>
                                                 </dependency>
                                                 <dependency>
                                                   <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                                                   <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
                                                   <version>4.2.0.RELEASE</version>
                                                 </dependency>
                                                 <dependency>
                                                   <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                                                   <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
                                                   <version>4.2.0.RELEASE</version>
                                                 </dependency>
                                                 <dependency>
                                                   <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                                                   <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
                                                   <version>4.2.0.RELEASE</version>
                                                 </dependency>
                                                 <dependency>
                                                   <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                                                   <artifactId>spring-webmvc-portlet</artifactId>
                                                   <version>4.2.0.RELEASE</version>
                                                 </dependency>
                                                 <dependency>
                                                   <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                                                   <artifactId>spring-websocket</artifactId>
                                                   <version>4.2.0.RELEASE</version>
                                                 </dependency>


                                                   <!-- Spring and Transactions -->
                                                   <dependency>
                                                       <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                                                       <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
                                                       <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
                                                   </dependency>
                                                   <dependency>
                                                       <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                                                       <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
                                                       <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
                                                   </dependency>

                                                   <!-- Logging with SLF4J & LogBack -->
                                                   <dependency>
                                                       <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                                                       <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                                                       <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
                                                       <scope>compile</scope>
                                                   </dependency>
                                                   <dependency>
                                                       <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                                                       <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
                                                       <version>${logback.version}</version>
                                                       <scope>runtime</scope>
                                                   </dependency>

                                                   <!-- Hibernate -->
                                                   <dependency>
                                                       <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                                                       <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
                                                       <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
                                                   </dependency>


                                                   <!-- Test Artifacts -->
                                                   <dependency>
                                                       <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                                                       <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
                                                       <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
                                                       <scope>test</scope>
                                                   </dependency>
                                                   <dependency>
                                                       <groupId>junit</groupId>
                                                       <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                                                       <version>${junit.version}</version>
                                                       <scope>test</scope>
                                                   </dependency>

                                               </dependencies> 
                                           </project>
   ```