# how to access to dependencies from maven-ant-plugin?

Tags: maven

My maven project has a few library dependencies defined in the  in pom.xml. I need to copy those dependencies to a folder during maven-antrun-plugin package phase. How can I do that?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps this can help you: add the goal copy-dependencies to phase package and configure a outputDirectory.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/996915/885650

Answer (score 0):

You can use [reference](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/examples/classpaths.html) to one of Maven classpaths

Answer (score 0):

In case you don't get an answer on how to do this from the ant plugin, take a look at the [copy goal of the maven dependency plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/copy-mojo.html).  I've used this successfully from the package phase.