# How to get Maven project jar library to another project

Tags: java, maven, web-applications

Hi I am developing a web application with maven structure so the maven create Maven Dependencies library to include the jar. My question is I need this library or jars in it so that I can use them to another non maven project like java project archetype in eclipse.

Comment: you have a maven jar project and you want jar out of it to reuse it in non maven project ?

Comment: yes that what I want..

Comment: you already have project and you just need jar out of it ?

Comment: yes means whatever jar's used in my maven project I want that all jars so that I can include them in lib of other project

Answer (score 1):

[You need to configure your `pom.xml` to create a fat jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16222748/how-to-build-fat-jar-with-maven) (jar including all of your dependencies inside jar) and then run `mvn clean package`

Comment: in that link you mention one maven plugin if I understood correct it will create jar for that maven project itself right?

Comment: yes including all of its dependencies inside jar, for example if you have dependency of `log4j` inside your project's `pom.xml` fat jar will have classes for your project + log4j jar in it

Comment: what if I only need log4j jar and not classes for my project?

Comment: You will need to use maven dependency plugin, [see reference](http://stackoverflow.com/a/996915/260990)

Comment: maven-dependency-plugin (goals "copy-dependencies", "unpack") is not supported by m2e this error I got any suggestions..?

Comment: I just added that plugin from the <plugin> </plugin> and added to my pom file in <plugins></plugins> tag it's give me error as mention above near  <execution> tag in eclipse