# Maven how to copy a specific folder inside a dependency to target/classes/myfolder

Tags: maven, maven-dependency-plugin

I have a dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
    <artifactId>swagger-ui</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Inside swagger-ui-2.1.4.jar has `META-INF/resources/webjars/`.
I would like to copy webjars/ folder to `target/classes/myfolder`

I've read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/97640/force-maven2-to-copy-dependencies-into-target-lib) and do the following:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>install</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <includeGroupIds>org.webjars</includeGroupIds>
                <includeArtifactIds>swagger-ui</includeArtifactIds>
                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classes/myfolder</outputDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

But it copies the `swagger-ui-2.1.4.jar` to the outputDirectory, which is not specifically what I need.

**Question**: Is there a possible solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You most probably don't need `copy-dependencies` but [`unpack`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/unpack-mojo.html). Check the [official example](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/unpacking-artifacts.html) for further details.

The following example:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.10</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>install</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>unpack</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <artifactItems>
                    <artifactItem>
                        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
                        <artifactId>swagger-ui</artifactId>
                        <version>2.1.4</version>
                        <type>jar</type>
                        <overWrite>false</overWrite>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classes/myfolder</outputDirectory>
                        <includes>META-INF/resources/**/*.*</includes>
                    </artifactItem>
                </artifactItems>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Will copy under `${project.build.directory}/classes/myfolder` the content of `META-INF/resources` which is basically the `webjars` folder. However you would also get the `META-INF/resources` tree structure.

---

To achieve exactly your intent (copy only a subfolder content of a dependency to a certain folder) you need to use two plugins: the `maven-dependency-plugin` and the `maven-resources-plugin` as following:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.10</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>install</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>unpack</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <artifactItems>
                    <artifactItem>
                        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
                        <artifactId>swagger-ui</artifactId>
                        <version>2.1.4</version>
                        <type>jar</type>
                        <overWrite>false</overWrite>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/tmp</outputDirectory>
                        <includes>META-INF/resources/**/*.*</includes>
                    </artifactItem>
                </artifactItems>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>copy-resources</id>
            <!-- here the phase you need -->
            <phase>install</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>copy-resources</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classes/myfolder</outputDirectory>
                <resources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>${project.build.directory}/tmp/META-INF/resources</directory>
                    </resource>
                </resources>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

The `maven-dependency-plugin` would copy our desired directory tree to the `target\tmp` folder, then the `maven-resources-plugin` would copy only the subfolder we want to the final directory.

Please note both plugins will be executed during the `install` phase but their declaration order it really important to have the final desired outcome.

Comment: Very nice solution. Thanks a lot for your time and answer