# How to copy the dependency jar in a target folder through Maven

Tags: java, maven

I am trying to make a jar of a project and then copy it to a target folder but it is not working. Below is the POM. 'Maven Install' does create the jar but it doesn't copy it to the lib folder.

pom.xml

```
<build>
<pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${java.version}</source>
                <target>${java.version}</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                    <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>/apps/dislocation/lib</outputDirectory>
                        <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
                        <overWriteSnapshots>false</overWriteSnapshots>
                        <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

Comment: It is the same question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/97640/force-maven-to-copy-dependencies-into-target-lib

Comment: By using `mvn clean package` it will be built and automatically being creating within `target` directory... ?

Comment: While inside maven don’t copy jars.  That is for a pubkishing step

Comment: @VolodyaLombrozo No, it isn't. The Dependency Plugin is the wrong choice here: "_make a jar of a project and then copy it_". That confused me at first, as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plugins just declared in [`<pluginManagement>`](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Plugin_Management) do nothing. This is just a configuration what to do when the plugin is declared elsewhere (in the same or in a module/child POM). You have to have a declaration in `<build>/<plugins>` somewhere, too:

> However, this only configures plugins that are actually referenced within the `plugins` element in the children or in the current POM.

[dependency:copy-dependencies](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/copy-dependencies-mojo.html) says:

> Goal that copies the project dependencies from the repository to a defined location.

That means `dependency:copy-dependencies` doesn't copy the JAR you create in the project but all that's declared under `<dependencies>`.

Furhermore, [the `prepare-package` phase comes long before the `install` phase](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Lifecycle_Reference), even the JAR is only created in the next phase (`package`) so there wouldn't be anything to copy from the repository – if it were the proper choice – at the `prepare-package` phase (though there can be an older version of the JAR from a previous `mvn install`).

So, you might think to add to your POM:

```xml
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
            <artifactId>${project.artifactId}</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

but this gives:

```text
[FATAL] 'dependencies.dependency.[<groupId>:<artifactId>:<version>]'
  for <groupId>:<artifactId>:<version> is referencing itself. @ line ..., column ...
```

So, you have to use one of those in [Best practices for copying files with Maven](https://stackoverflow.com/q/586202/1744774).