# How to export a java Maven file from eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jar, export

How to export a java maven file from eclipse with all external libraries and maven dependacies so the other peorson opening does not have to download and import the external libraries?

I tried the Archive file exporting method. But it wasn't successful, cause it lost the external libraries while importing, and it lost clases and packages .

Comment: The whole point about a Maven build file is that it gets the dependencies for you. In theory all you need to do is give them pom.xml and it will do all that's required

Comment: Its the thing that its a java project with maven dependancies, cant have one without having the other

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your comment at all

Comment: If you like to achieve that you have to make a configuration to build a resulting jar (executable jar via maven-shade-plugin/maven-assembly-plugin) or creating a zip/tar archive with maven-assembly-plugin depending on your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

The default local repository is located based on OS:

> Windows: C:\Users<User_Name>.m2

> Linux: /home/<User_Name>/.m2

> Mac: /Users/<user_name>/.m2

Assuming that you want to store these dependencies in the project folder so that every user **does not have to download and import the external libraries**  according to  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21641165/14613856) source you can download all your dependencies to the target folder with the  following command.

> mvn install dependency:copy-dependencies

You can also specify the folder.

> mvn dependency:copy-dependencies -DoutputDirectory=specific-folder/

To make use of these commands you will have to install [Apache Maven Dependency Plugin](https://does%20not%20have%20to%20download%20and%20import%20the%20external%20libraries)

Comment: did not work :(

Comment: What is the error message?