# Using maven as a dependency tool

Tags: java, maven

When I use `mvn install`, it hides my downloaded files ! `[[mystery music]]`

```java
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Main.class);
    logger.info("Example log from {}", Main.class.getSimpleName());
  }
}
```

I can manually download the relevant jars, and everything is fine:

```bash
$ wget https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/2.0.7/slf4j-api-2.0.7.jar
$ wget https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/slf4j/slf4j-simple/2.0.7/slf4j-simple-2.0.7.jar
$ java -cp slf4j-api-2.0.7.jar:slf4j-simple-2.0.7.jar Main.java
[main] INFO Main - Example log from Main
```

When I try using `pom.xml`, it doesn't work:

```
<project>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.mycompany.app</groupId>
  <artifactId>my-app</artifactId>
  <version>1</version>
  <dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.7</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.7</version>
  </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

I *do* see the `*.jar` files get downloaded, but I have no idea where they end up

```
$ mvn install
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ----------------------< com.mycompany.app:my-app >----------------------
[INFO] Building my-app 1
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/slf4j/slf4j-simple/2.0.7/slf4j-simple-2.0.7.pom
Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/slf4j/slf4j-simple/2.0.7/slf4j-simple-2.0.7.pom (1.1 kB at 2.4 kB/s)
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/slf4j/slf4j-simple/2.0.7/slf4j-simple-2.0.7.jar
Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/slf4j/slf4j-simple/2.0.7/slf4j-simple-2.0.7.jar (16 kB at 139 kB/s)
```

Comment: Did you check in the default maven dependency download location? .m2 folder?

Comment: OMG you're right ! they are there ! We should probably search for a duplicate to close this question

Comment: I voted to close my question as a duplicate

Comment: Aside: If you want to copy a project's JARs to a specific directory (e.g. so they are all in one place), you can use Maven's [copy-dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/q/97640/12567365).